# Linear Transformation - One-One and Onto Property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

"If T is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space, then T is one-one implies T must be onto. Also T is onto implies T must be one-one."

I do not understand the proof of this.

Does it come from this --

- For a finite dimensional vector space,

  1. T is invertible iff T is one-one.
  2. T is invertible iff T is onto.

So from statement 1 and 2, we can say that T is one-one if T is onto and vice-versa.

Does proof of this kind is valid, if A implies B and B in turn implies A , and similarly A implies C and C in turn implies A, then can we say that B implies C?

Comment: Yes. Your property definitely follows from those two. It also follows from the fact that $dim(Ker T)+dim(Im T)=dim(V)$. When one-to-one, the kernel is trivial and then the range is the whole space and viceversa.

Comment: bi-implication is same as "equal", so the proof structure is A=B, A=C => B=C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $T \in L(U,V)$ to be one-one, where $dim(U)$ and $dim(V)$ are finite.

$T$ is one-one $\iff ker(T)=\{\underline{0}\} \iff dim(ker(T))=0$

So by Rank–nullity theorem, 
$$rank(T)+dim(ker(T))=dim(U)$$
$$\implies rank(T)=dim(U)$$

So now all vectors from $range(T)$ can be mapped by *some vectors* from $U$, that means it is onto. But we assumed that $T$ is one-one, so *some vectors* means **one vector** only.

Now, suppose $T$ is onto. Then all $\underline{y} \in V$ can be written as

$T(\underline{x})= \underline{y}$ , where $\underline{x} \in U$

So it is clear that $rank(T)=dim(V)$.

Hence $dim(ker(T)) = dim(U)-rank(T) = dim(U)-dim(V) = 0$ 
$$\iff ker(T)=\{\underline{0}\}$$ 
$\iff T $ is one-one

Comment: And how to prove the converse, i.e. one-one from onto ?

Comment: Thanks! I have added the converse of the proof, but you need to prove why T is one-one iff ker(T)={0} by yourself